# Custom sorting multiple levels of column index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

What is the best way to maintain the ordering of level2 (Checks, Check Avg, Checks, Check AVg etc..), but sort the dates of the parent level in ascending order?

Comment: what is parent level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `sort_remaining=False` to [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to prevent sorting levels below specified:

```
df = df.sort_index(level=0, axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
```

`df`:

```
Week        2021-10-11           2021-10-18           2021-10-25          
                Checks Check Avg     Checks Check Avg     Checks Check Avg
11th Street          4         5          2         3          0         1
16th Street         10        11          8         9          6         7
Bala Cynwyd         16        17         14        15         12        13
```

---

Sample Data Used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(18).reshape((-1, 6)),
    index=['11th Street', '16th Street', 'Bala Cynwyd'],
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
        [np.repeat(pd.to_datetime(['2021-10-25', '2021-10-18', '2021-10-11']),
                   2),
         ['Checks', 'Check Avg'] * 3],
        names=['Week', None]
    )
)
```

`df`:

```
Week        2021-10-25           2021-10-18           2021-10-11          
                Checks Check Avg     Checks Check Avg     Checks Check Avg
11th Street          0         1          2         3          4         5
16th Street          6         7          8         9         10        11
Bala Cynwyd         12        13         14        15         16        17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort_index` on `axis=1`. You can specify the sorting order per level.

Example input:

```
   a  b     c     a  c  b  a
   X  Y  Z  Y  X  Z  Z  X  Y
0  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

sorting:

```
df = df.sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[True, False], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   a        b        c      
   Z  Y  X  Z  Y  X  Z  Y  X
0  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```